# Pushing the resultset data onto a nested hashmap with a List

Tags: java, jdbc, hashmap

I'm trying to push my resultset data onto a nested map. Honestly, I've been struggling with the logic of how to do it. Here's a sample of my resultset data,

```
ID Main    Sub
1  Root    Carrots
2  Root    Beets
3  Root    Turnips
4  Leafy   Spinach
5  Leafy   Celery
6  Fruits  Apples
7  Fruits  Oranges
```

I created a hashmap `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, List<String>>>`, in which I thought the innermap could hold the main col as key and the corresponding subs as the list of values. The outermap would contain the id as the key and the corresponding map as the value. I'm struggling to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your identifiers are consecutive, you don't need the outer `HashMap`. Just store the inner `HashMap`s in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You just need `HashMap<Integer, List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer to your question. But the question is probably wrong. Since the ID is unique (just a guess) you're probably looking for

```
Map<Integer, DataObject> map = new HashMap<>();
```

where DataObject is a POJO containing the variabels `main` and `sub`. Adding data to such a structure is easy.

Answer to question (added to show you how Maps and Lists work):

```
private Map<Integer, Map<String, List<String>>> map = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Tester().go();
}

private void go() {
    add(1, "Root", "Carrots");
    add(2, "Root", "Beets");
    add(3, "Root", "Turnips");
    add(4, "Leafy", "Spinach");
    add(5, "Leafy", "Celery");
    add(6, "Fruits", "Apples");
    add(7, "Fruits", "Oranges");
}

private void add(int id, String main, String sub) {
    if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
        map.put(id, new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
    }
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(sub);
    map.get(id).put(main, list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a different structure.
You have unique Id's and sub, but your Main can be duplicate.
Thus I would suggest using the following structure:
HashMap>
where POJO has ID and sub.
the key of map would be main.
Thus you can easily do:

```
if (map.get(main)==null){
List<POJO> pojoList= new List<>();
    pojolist.add(pojo);
}else{
    List<POJO> pojoList=map.get(main);
    pojoList.add(pojo);
}
```

But it ultimately depends if you need to do lookup using ID or main.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make nested hash maps because each row in the example is unique (each List in nested map will have only one value).

In any case here is algorithm example in Java 8 style for your particular need :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ResultSet> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add(new ResultSet().setId(1).setMain("Root").setSub("Carrots"));
        rows.add(new ResultSet().setId(2).setMain("Root").setSub("Beets"));
        rows.add(new ResultSet().setId(3).setMain("Root").setSub("Turnips"));
        rows.add(new ResultSet().setId(4).setMain("Leafy").setSub("Spinach"));
        rows.add(new ResultSet().setId(5).setMain("Leafy").setSub("Celery"));
        rows.add(new ResultSet().setId(6).setMain("Fruits").setSub("Apples"));
        rows.add(new ResultSet().setId(7).setMain("Fruits").setSub("Oranges"));

        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, List<String>>>  result = new HashMap<>();
        rows.forEach(row -> {
            HashMap<String, List<String>> subsByMain = result.getOrDefault(row.getId(), new HashMap<>());
            List<String> subs = subsByMain.getOrDefault(row.getMain(), new ArrayList<>());
            subs.add(row.getSub());
            subsByMain.put(row.getMain(), subs);
            result.put(row.getId(), subsByMain);
        });
    }


    static class ResultSet {
        private Integer id;
        private String main;
        private String sub;

        Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        ResultSet setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        String getMain() {
            return main;
        }

        ResultSet setMain(String main) {
            this.main = main;
            return this;
        }

        String getSub() {
            return sub;
        }

        ResultSet setSub(String sub) {
            this.sub = sub;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```